# Azure App Service Backend - Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

We are planning to use Azure App Service for our App. I've never worked with azure and the entity framework and it's absolutely new to me.

Our current problem is that the example backend project, which you can download from the Azure Website, refers very much to the entity framework "code first" pattern. I understand this pattern and can work well with it but unfortunately it does not matter for us since we have to use an existing database.

Are there any good tutorials or other resources to use a "database first" pattern with the Azure App Service backend?

Comment: You can do code first from an existing database. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx. You can then follow the the example from the Azure website.

Comment: that helped me alot. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the models for Azure Mobile Apps (which you tagged) - check out Chapter 3 of http://aka.ms/zumobook for details.